# Emails generated in loop not sending subject

Tags: python, email, for-loop, smtplib

The following script sends correctly:

```
import smtplib, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="fdsafsa")
parser.add_argument('-r', nargs='?', default=False, help='help')
args = parser.parse_args()
foo = 1
baz = 'fdsa'
TEXT = 'This is the message %d%s' %(foo,baz)

message = '\
From: me@yahoo.com \n\
To: %s \n\
Subject: Data saved successfully \n\
%s' %(args.r,TEXT)

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail('me@yahoo.com',args.r,message)
```

But this script does not send emails correctly (note the `for loop`)

```
import smtplib, argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="fdsafsa")
parser.add_argument('-r', nargs='?', default=False, help='help')
args = parser.parse_args()
for ii in range(2):
    foo = 1d
    baz = 'fdsa'
    TEXT = 'This is the message %d%s' %(foo,baz)

    message = '\
    From: me@yahoo.com \n\
    To: %s \n\
    Subject: Data saved successfully \n\
    %s' %(args.r,TEXT)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail('me@yahoo.com',args.r,message)
```

In the latter example, the email contains no subject or from field. They appear in the body instead.

example body:

From: me@yahoo.com

To: me@yahoo.com

Subject: Data saved successfully

This is the message 1fdsa

In the former example only the "This is a the message 1fdsa" part appears in the body. Why does the smtplib module not correctly read the from, to, and subject fields from `message` when they are in a `for loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've indented the code as part of the loop, but the multi-line string also includes the leading spaces on each line as part of the string itself - as you'd see if you printed it out. Email is very sensitive to things like that, so it no longer sees those lines as headers.

It's much better to do this via string concatenation:

```
message = (
    'From: me@yahoo.com \n'
    'To: %s \n'
    'Subject: Data saved successfully \n'
     '%s' %(args.r,TEXT)
)
```

Since those lines are all inside parentheses, they will be automatically concatenated.